# How to define conditional compiler symbols for specific sdk in uwp

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal

I'm writing a UWP app in Visual Studio 2015. Minimum sdk is 10240. Maximum is 14393. I want to write sdk specific code, so I want to define a conditional compilation symbol. I can simply define it in the project properties window under build tab. But where I can define the condition?

Simply what I want to archive is this. I have define a symbol in build tab 'SDK_14393'.. then I have some code like this which I want to execute only in 14393 sdk,

```
#if SDK_14393
  //some code here
#endif
```

But it executes all the time even when I'm in a different sdk. So my question is how to archive this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#ifdef` is not the right tool to build adaptive code, because you'll need to ship two versions of your app. And the OS version number / SDK version is not a good discriminator.

If you're calling WinRT APIs, use the [`ApiInformation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.foundation.metadata.apiinformation.aspx) type to see if the feature you want is available at runtime. If you're calling Win32 then use delayload and the [`QueryOptionalDelayLoadedAPI`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt403328(v=vs.85).aspx) function.

Comment: Thank you. Solved my problem. But If I want, can I define a condition? i mean not for a sdk scenario

Comment: Yes - you should look into [different build configurations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kkz9kefa.aspx) in VS.