# How do you detect the availability of global functions in UWP version adaptive apps?

Tags: uwp

UWP provides [Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.metadata.apiinformation) to detect the availability of types, methods, enum constants, etc, but how do you detect the availability of new global functions?

For example, `DXGIDeclareAdapterRemovalSupport` was added after the initial release of Windows 10. Is it possible to write a single UWP app that works on versions of Windows before `DXGIDeclareAdapterRemovalSupport` was added but calls it on newer versions where available?

In a traditional Win32/Desktop app, you can call `LoadLibrary(...)` and `GetProcAddress(...)` or similar, but that's not possible with UWP (`LoadPackagedLibrary` is available but it won't load system libraries like `dxgi.dll`).

Bonus question: why exactly is it possible to compile a program that conditionally uses a new WinRT API and load/run that program on versions of Windows where that API isn't available, but attempting to do the same with a global function like `DXGIDeclareAdapterRemovalSupport` results in a dynamic linker error at load time?

Comment: Could you tell why you want to detect the availability of global functions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to define conditional compiler symbols for specific sdk in uwp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40434424/how-to-define-conditional-compiler-symbols-for-specific-sdk-in-uwp) (Title is misleading, the question is actually about runtime detection, not compile-time.)

Comment: Thanks @RaymondChen! That did answer my question. I provided a more detailed answer to my own specific questions below, but you deserve the credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[QueryOptionalDelayLoadedAPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi2/nf-libloaderapi2-queryoptionaldelayloadedapi) is available for exactly this purpose. From its documentation (emphasis mine):

> Applications that target multiple versions of Windows or multiple
> Windows device families also rely on delay-loaded DLLs to make visible
> extra features when they are available.
>
> A desktop application can use delayed loading as an alternative to
> runtime dynamic linking that uses LoadLibrary or LoadLibraryEx to load
> a DLL and GetProcAddress to get a pointer to a function. **A Windows
> Store app cannot use LoadLibrary or LoadLibraryEx, so to get the
> benefits to runtime dynamic linking, a Windows Store app must use the
> delayed loading mechanism.**
>
> To check whether a function in a delay-loaded DLL is available on the
> system, the application calls QueryOptionalDelayLoadedAPI with the
> specified function. If QueryOptionalDelayLoadedAPI succeeds, the
> application can safely call the specified function.

Raymond Chen's *The Old New Thing* blog gives a ["tiny demonstration"](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20170322-00/?p=95796):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <commdlg.h>
#include <libloaderapi2.h>
#include <stdio.h>

EXTERN_C IMAGE_DOS_HEADER __ImageBase;
#define HMODULE_THISCOMPONENT reinterpret_cast<HMODULE>(&__ImageBase)

int __cdecl main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (QueryOptionalDelayLoadedAPI(HMODULE_THISCOMPONENT,
          "comdlg32.dll", "GetOpenFileNameW", 0))
    {
        printf("GetOpenFileNameW can be called!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As for the bonus question: the WinRT type system implements runtime loading of API's using a concept called "activation". See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/winrt-cref/winrt-type-system for more details.