# How to handle a missing function in a delay-loaded DLL when using MSVC 16?

Tags: c++, windows, dll, delay-load

In macOS, I can use weak linking to allow use of older versions of a library. In that case, any function I've linked to that's not present in the library resolves to null, and I can check whether the function is available before calling it, e.g.

`if (functionName) { functionName(); }`

It looks like the closest mechanism in Windows is to use delay-loaded DLLs. (I am specifically compiling with MSVC 16). After reading through their docs, though, it's not clear to me what happens if a procedure in a delay-loaded DLL is missing. What would be most convenient for me is it working just like weak linking on macOS, so that missing functions resolves to null.

Is there a way to do that? Otherwise how does one handle missing procedures in a delay-loaded DLL?

In case it matters, this is a Qt 6.2.1 app.

<strike>EDIT: I tried using `QueryOptionalDelayLoadedAPI()` and found that it does not work. Here is the code I'm using, with DLL and function names replaced. `MyFunction` takes a single C string argument and returns 0.</strike>

```
qDebug() << QueryOptionalDelayLoadedAPI(GetModuleHandle(NULL), "mydll.dll", "MyFunction", 0);
// Prints 0 erroneously
qDebug() << MyFunction("");
// Prints 0 correctly
```

EDIT: `QueryOptionalDelayLoadedAPI()` does work, but requires the mangled name if the function is a C++ function.

Comment: QueryOptionalDelayLoadedAPI

Comment: One way is to manually `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`, but I don't know much about this, and maybe there's a better way.

Comment: @RaymondChen That seems promising. Do you want to submit a full answer to the question?

Comment: @BriBri: delay loading is part of your compiler's runtime library.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/understanding-the-helper-function?view=msvc-170 for how to receive hook/callback of delay load failures -- if using Visual C++ compiler.  You really need to add compiler version to your question.

Comment: @BenVoigt I have edited the question to mention my compiler. (MSVC 16)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you detect the availability of global functions in UWP version adaptive apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62797686/how-do-you-detect-the-availability-of-global-functions-in-uwp-version-adaptive-a)

Comment: by fact you can implement `PDELAYLOAD_FAILURE_DLL_CALLBACK` function and assign it pointer to  `__pfnDliFailureHook2`

Comment: @RaymondChen: Given that OP seems to want to share code between macOS and Windows builds, it seems very unlikely that UWP is involved

Comment: @RaymondChen I tried QueryOptionalDelayLoadedAPI but it's always returning false even when the function is available. I'm not sure if I'm using it wrong or if it just doesn't work for my use case.

Comment: @BriBri then please [edit] your question to include the code that is not working for you

Comment: The first parameter to QueryOptionalDelayLoadedAPI  is a handle to the module that is performing the delay-loading. You want to pass your own module handle, not the executable's module handle. The sample code in the documentation uses the `static_cast<HMODULE>(&__ImageBase)` trick to do this.

Comment: @RaymondChen the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi2/nf-libloaderapi2-queryoptionaldelayloadedapi) says only Windows Store apps should do that, desktop apps should use `GetModuleHandle/Ex()` instead.

Comment: @BriBri is the function actually exported as `MyFunction`, or is it exported as something more like `_MyFunction` or `MyFunction@<#>`

Comment: I believe it's MyFunction, though I tried _MyFunction as well. It is declared `cdecl`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Store apps must use the `__ImageBase` trick because `GetModuleHandle/Ex` is disallowed from Store apps. Win32 apps can use `__ImageBase` or use the `HINSTANCE` they received in `DllMain`, or `GetModuleHandle` if they know that their DLL name is unique, or `GetModuleHandleEx` with `
GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS` and an address from their own DLL. But `GetModuleHandle(NULL)` will give you the executable handle, not your DLL's handle.

Comment: @RaymondChen at no point did the OP say the delay-loaded function is being called from another DLL. It is being called from a Windows app. So the exe handle should suffice. But, I find it odd that this API even needs the *caller's* handle at all. I guess it digs into the caller's PE header to lookup its delay-load table?

Comment: @RemyLebeau It needs to know which module's delay-load table to look at. Otherwise, how would it know where to look?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Turns out I was mistaken, the function in question *was* a C++ function, and therefore I needed to use the mangled name.

Comment: Use a DEF file so that the exported name is unmangled. This is recommended because C++ mangling is not standardized, so it is not portable between toolchains.